# .NET Interop vs PHP - VT_ARRAY | VT_UNKNOWN (0x200D)

Tags: c#, php, .net, com-interop

Someone asked me to use my .NET 4 Interop library from PHP. I have some trouble with that. In PHP when I call variant_get_type() for a certain array, it says "2085" (0x200D). PHP is unable to iterate this array.

In my .NET assembly:

```
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType=AutoDual)]
[ProgId("mylib")]
public class Client {
    ...
    public Whatever[] getWhatevers();
        ...
    }

    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType=AutoDual)]
    [ProgId("mylib.Whatever")]
    public class Whatever { ... }
    ...
}
```

How should I modify my .NET library for PHP to accept this Whatever[] array from .NET and iterate it?